# Changing Data Types in Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, selenium, sqlalchemy

Below is the last part of my selenium web scraper that loops through the different tabs of this [website page](https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=y&type=8&season=2018&month=0&season1=2018&ind=0), selects the "export data" button, downloads the data, adds a "yearid" column, then loads the data into a MySQL table.

```
    df = pd.read_csv(desired_filepath)
    df = df.replace('%','',regex=True)
    df["yearid"] = datetime.today().year
    df.to_csv(desired_filepath)

    engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost/{db}"
                           .format(user="walker",
                                   pw="password",
                                   db="data"))
    df.to_sql(con=engine, name='fg_test_hitting_{}'.format(button_text), if_exists='replace')

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

The scraper works great, however when the data gets loaded into the MySQL table, there are certain columns that get loaded as TEXT when they should be loaded as numeric, preferably a DOUBLE data type. I noticed this only occurs in the column names that have a % sign at the end of the string (i.e. BB%). I have eliminated the % sign in all rows underneath the column headers, but the data is still loading into MYSQL as TEXT. Is there any way to change the data type for all columns that have a % sign in the column name before the data gets loaded into MySQL? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please narrow your problem down. Is the whole selenium code really necessary to answer your (title) question?

Comment: Is this version better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo:

parse URL into a DF:

```
In [263]: df = pd.read_html(url, header=1)[11]
```

show problematic columns:

```
In [264]: df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('%')]]
Out[264]:
       BB%      K%
0   18.5 %  19.2 %
1   12.8 %  11.5 %
2   11.0 %  13.1 %
3    8.7 %  18.3 %
4   13.5 %  16.0 %
..     ...     ...
26   7.0 %  20.2 %
27  13.5 %  12.5 %
28   9.4 %  16.1 %
29   8.6 %  21.5 %
30     NaN     NaN

[31 rows x 2 columns]
```

converting them to numeric columns:

```
In [265]: df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('%')]] = \
              (df.filter(regex='%')
                 .apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.str.replace(r'[\s%]',''), 
                                                errors='coerce')))
```

result:

```
In [266]: df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('%')]]
Out[266]:
     BB%    K%
0   18.5  19.2
1   12.8  11.5
2   11.0  13.1
3    8.7  18.3
4   13.5  16.0
..   ...   ...
26   7.0  20.2
27  13.5  12.5
28   9.4  16.1
29   8.6  21.5
30   NaN   NaN

[31 rows x 2 columns]

In [267]: df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('%')]].dtypes
Out[267]:
BB%    float64
K%     float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you MaxU! Really appreciate the detailed response!

Comment: Quick question...there is one annoying column titled 'HR/FB' that uses a % sign after each value. Can `df.columns.str.contains` search for the '%' sign and the column 'HR/FB'? I've tried using the | operand but I keep getting an error. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @NateWalker, try this: `df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'(?:%|HR\/FB)')]]`

Comment: Not sure why this is occuring, but the scraper runs, gets about halfway through, then triggers the error "Columns must be same length as key." I never got that error when I searched for just the % sign. Any thoughts? Appreciate all the help with this!

Comment: @NateWalker, which line of code produces this error?

Comment: my PyCharm IDE is not being very specific with the error. It shows these two errors.. `in __setitem__
    self._setitem_array(key, value)` and `in _setitem_array
    raise ValueError('Columns must be same length as key')` The code works fine when `df.columns.str.contains(%)` so I think it has something to do with that line.

Comment: @NateWalker, I hope you used the same RegEx also for `df.filter(regex=r'(?:%|HR\/FB)')` ?